# Can we call multiple javascript function onKeyUp event? because i am not able to do it

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura-attribute

<aura:set attribute="actions">

```
            <div onkeyup="{! c.handleKeyUp }; {!c.handleChange}" >
                <lightning:input
                    aura:id="enter-search"
                    name="enter-search"
                    placeholder="Enter the Tag or Name"
                    type="search"
                    style="margin-bottom: 20px;"
                />
            </div>
        </aura:set>`
```

`

Comment: hey why don't you call the another function from the first function

Comment: Or, add a specific function that calls both and assign just that one function. This is the right way to address this problem, since you cannot assign multiple callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for help gopal and phill w.